# Image not saving in photo Album

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, screenshot

I invoke UIImagePicker controller. When i click camera button, preview and use button only displaying, my image is not saving in photo Album.

code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];


    // Set the image picker source:
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Hide the controls:
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // Make camera view full screen:
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Insert the overlay:
    picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view;

      self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // Show the picker:
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

first set `UIImagePickerController` delegte self`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegte = self ;

    // Set the image picker source:
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Hide the controls:
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // Make camera view full screen:
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Insert the overlay:
    picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view;

      self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // Show the picker:
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
        {
         UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
        }

    - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
        UIAlertView *alert;


        if (error)
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                               message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
        else 
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                               message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

Comment: where to use this line? Inside viewDidAppear?

Comment: this is UIImagePickerController delegte method

Comment: No. It's not saving to photo Album

Comment: can you set UIImagePickerController delegate

Comment: first you set delegate first  picker.delegte = self

Comment: and also put breakpoint at this delegte mehod and check if the delegate is called or not

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info

{
     UIImage *img=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

      //save the merged image to photo album
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: put breakpoint at this mehod and check if the delegate is called